# Как определить что картинка была ретуширована?

Tags: java, python

Нужно определить была ли картинка ретуширована (например вставили часть другого изображения), есть ли готовые решения для этого на python 3.6 или java?

Comment: Хорошо отретушированную картинку вряд ли получится определить

Comment: Ну тут надо искать методы поиска артефактов, либо по цвету, либо сжатия. Основная идея в том, что разброс по цвету и яркости в тех местах, где ретуши не было, будет меньше. А чтобы определить была ли картинка отретуширована, нужно сначала найти места с однородным цветом, без больших перепадов, а потом уже смотреть разброс цветов и яркости. По идеии, разброс н всех участках должен быть одинаковым